# Advice on A/B testing price?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-optimize

Just wondering how do you go about A/B testing price on an e-commerce site using WooCommerce? I have used 2 methods both with drawbacks. Was wondering what alternatives you guys have.

**Method 1:**

If I use Google Optimize, I am able to change the price a user sees.

Original: Price on page = $10

Variant 1: Price on page = $20

*Problem with Method 1:*

However, even if I edit the page to show $20 when a user clicks Add to Cart, they would still add the $10 version of the product. Clearly, this is not ideal for testing purposes since I want to see how many users actually checked out at the $20 price point.

**Method 2:**

Have different landing pages that show different products. Using my e-commerce plugin (WooCommerce), I can then add different prices for the same product (ie. add the same product twice just that they have different prices). This way the price a user sees is actually what is added to their cart.

Original (on www.homepage.com): Price on page = $10

Variant 1 (on www.homepage.com/variant1): Price on page = $20

*Problem with Method 2:*

A user who lands on the $20 page can easily go back to the homepage ( to find that they are actually being charged more). This sounds like it would lead to negative customer experience.

**Question:**

Which method is better and how do you mitigate the problems they pose? Or are there better ways of dealing with this?

Thanks!